# How To Throw Errors In Apollo Server v4?

Tags: typescript, graphql, apollo-server, typegraphql

thanks for looking into this. So I am trying to migrate my Apollo Server from V3 to V4, I have a resolver that type checks for an Access Token and returns it like so

```
export class LoginResolver {
    @Mutation(() => AccessToken)
    async login(
        @Arg("email") email: string,
        @Arg("password") password: string,
        @Ctx() { prisma, res }: ProjectContext
    ): Promise<AccessToken> {
        // check if user exists
        const user = await prisma.user.findFirst({
            where: {
                email,
            },
        });
        if (!user) {
            throw new GraphQLError("No user found");
        }
        const valid = await verify(user.password, password);
        if (!valid) {
            throw new GraphQLError("Invalid Password");
        }
        // the user logged in successully
        res.cookie("*****", createRefreshToken(user), { httpOnly: true });
        const accessToken = createAccessToken(user);
        return {
            accessToken,
        };
    }
}
```

It returns the following error if the validation fails.

```
{
  "data": {},
  "error": {
    "message": "JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data"
  }
}
```

But however, if the right credentials were provided the API works just fine returning me a access token

```
{
  "data": {
    "login": {
      "accessToken": "..."
    }
  }
}
```

Correct Input:
email : email@gmail.com
password : password

Initially in Apollo V3 I had standard throw statements that worked just fine

```
        const user = await prisma.user.findFirst({
            where: {
                email,
            },
        });
        if (!user) {
            throw new Error("No user found");
        }
        const valid = await verify(user.password, password);
        if (!valid) {
            throw new Error("Invalid Password");
        }
```

digging into Apollo server's docs I found that in V4 Apollo Error was removed and GraphQLError from graphql took it's place, I gave that a shot but that does not seem to fix it.

Error Message from the console :

```
Unexpected error processing request: TypeError: graphqlError.toJSON is not a function
TypeError: graphqlError.toJSON is not a function
    at enrichError (D:\Projects\PlacementHub\backend\node_modules\@apollo\server\src\errorNormalize.ts:84:30)
    at D:\Projects\PlacementHub\backend\node_modules\@apollo\server\src\errorNormalize.ts:46:18
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at normalizeAndFormatErrors (D:\Projects\PlacementHub\backend\node_modules\@apollo\server\src\errorNormalize.ts:39:29)
    at ApolloServer.errorResponse (D:\Projects\PlacementHub\backend\node_modules\@apollo\server\src\ApolloServer.ts:1028:73)
    at ApolloServer.executeHTTPGraphQLRequest (D:\Projects\PlacementHub\backend\node_modules\@apollo\server\src\ApolloServer.ts:1020:19)
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that [GraphQLError](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/data/errors/#custom-errors) has a mandatory 2nd argument and Apollo isn't handling it well if it's omitted.

try

```
throw new GraphQLError('"No user found', {
  extensions: {
    code: 'UNKNOWN_USER',
  },
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I experienced similar problems when I switched from v3 to v4. If you want to show custom errors in the resolver, using **GraphQLError** is enough.

In the past, it tolerated `throw new Error` usage. This behavior no longer works like it used to. You have to use **GraphQLError** instead. If you throw new Error like the past, your server will stop working.

**Package versions that I have tested and are compatible with:**

```json
"graphql": "16.8.1",
"@apollo/server": "4.9.4",
"express": "4.18.2",
```

**GraphQL has three different error types:**

- Syntax errors (e.g., a query was malformed)
- Validation errors (e.g., a query included a schema field that doesn't exist)
- Resolver errors (e.g., an error occurred while attempting to populate
  a query field)

I hope I helped you. You can review the documentation for more information. By the way, it would be beneficial for you to consider the NodeJS version separately.

```js
throw new GraphQLError('Invalid argument value', {
    extensions: {
        code: 'BAD_USER_INPUT',
    },
});
```

https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/data/error-handling

Answer (score -3):

You should use ApolloError for this.

```js
import { ApolloError } from 'apollo-server-express';

throw new ApolloError("there is a big problem");
```

I did the one for Express in the above line of code. You can download other packages according to your project.

Comment: Yeahh but in V4 they have removed Apollo Error?

Comment: Probably yes, apolloError removed